# basic angular component won't render

Tags: angular

I'm fairly new to angular and I'm having issues with a component that won't render.

The parent html calls the component like this:

```
<app-models-sd-passages [passages]="" ></app-models-sd-passages>
```

And the component code looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-models-sd-passages',
  styleUrls: ['./sd.component.scss'],
  template: `
    <div id="passages_id">
      <p>
        Passages
      </p>
    </div>
  `
})
export class PassagesComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() passages;

  constructor()
  {
  };

  ngOnInit()
  {
  }
}
```

The rendered page is simply empty with this in the html inspect:

```
<app-models-sd-passages _ngcontent-ato-c154="" class="ng-star-inserted"></app-models-sd-passages>
```

Comment: Can you post the contents of AppModule file, just want to cross check if PassagesComponent is defined within declaration array of NgModule within AppComponent.

Comment: Also in your SCSS file is there any style written to for "passages_id" dom element?

Comment: the app module file was the issue! I forgot to put my component there

Comment: voting to close as a typo....